# Authenticate imported Azure AD user using Graph API

Tags: azure, azure-ad-graph-api

I am using Azure Graph API to get all the user information from Azure AD. After that I am adding those users into my application. In the login page I want them to enter their username and the password they use in AD. I don't want to store their password in my table but I want to do an authentication check. Is there a rest service in Graph API which does this ?

Comment: It is a bad idea to store  username/passwords in your database. General approach is to have the application redirect them to Azure AD for authentication and have Azure AD return back the claims which contain some information about the user. You can store that information in your database to identify them when they login again in your application.

Comment: I am not storing their password in my db. I am providing SAML based authentication . In addition I want to allow them to login through my normal login page providing their credentials. I won't be storing it anywhere. I just want to authenticate them using Azure AD API.

Answer (score 1):

> In the login page I want them to enter their username and the password they use in AD. I don't want to store their password in my table but I want to do an authentication check. Is there a rest service in Graph API which does this ?

This is doesn't relate to the rest service about Graph API. It determined by how you protect your service.

For example, the Microsoft provide the Azure Graph API which protected by Azure AD. And the Azure AD supports the [OAuth 2.0](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749) to get the access token to access the protected resource.

In the scenario you described, you can consider use **OAuth 2.0 code grant flow**. Please see the figure below for the detail steps for this flow:

[image]

Here is the code sample to using this flow for your reference:

[active-directory-dotnet-graphapi-web](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-graphapi-web.git)

[active-directory-dotnet-graphapi-console](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-graphapi-console)

Comment: My login portal asks for username and password. Once they provide the user name I can get the client id, tenant id and secret key(which i am using to create the access token ) . Now I am able to connect to Azure AD using this access token it means these three fields i provided correct during the configuration and it is a valid Oauth. I want to authenticate the user who is trying to login to my application using their Azue AD credentials

Comment: @Jerry Did you have any issue at present now. I am not able to follow the question you were handling.

Comment: Yeah. I am able to import users from Azure Directory using OAuth token. Now when the imported user tries to login to my application, I want to check whether they are entering the right credential for their azure AD. Currently I am calling this service to get the user password profile and compare the password with the entered password . https://graph.windows.net/%s/users/"+userName+"/?api-version=2013-04-05. This doesn't look like a proper way and moreover I am getting password as null in this service

Comment: Based on my understanding, our application shouldn't verify the users' password. This is responsibility of the identity provider(Azure AD). And this is not safe for the users enter their Azure AD account credential on an third-party app.  We need to redirect the OP to the Azure AD login page. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-authentication-scenarios) is helpful link about authentication scenario for Azure AD.

Comment: If I want to get their password in AD, how can I get it. I am calling the Graph API url to get complete user profile, in that one object is password profile but it gives me null value always. Do I have to set any extra permissions for the app?

Comment: @Jerry you cannot access the user password by any means. That is the reason why you won't be able to authenticate the user on you app. It has to be done against the Azure AD only.